# Modifying the location and position of a window opened from Desktop.Browser

Tags: java, browser, window, lwjgl

```
    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) 
    {
        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(URI.create(URL));
    }
```

How would I go about editing the location and size of the window opened here? It will need to be possible to do cross-platform. If there is no solution for cross-platform, what are solutions for anything Desktop works with?

(This is straying off question, but could I also zoom into part of the webpage?)

(Also off-question, but if there is another way to open the window, with the handle included, how could this be done?)

Comment: I know a platform-dependent solution but only for Windows, and it would require JNA or JNI.

Comment: I would need it to be cross platform, but I'm interested in your method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience, the `getDesktop().browse(URI.create(URL));` does not work on Mac, so even if you can find the equivalent of @Hovercraft  Full of Eels solution for the Mac, it wouldn't matter.

I haven't tested Desktop with Java 7.1 yet on the Mac, but it hasn't worked with previous version of Java.

If you really want cross platform, I think you need to use the WebView in JavaFX - JavaFX is now available on the Mac and it is a fully functional browser.  There are lots of tutorials out there on mixing JavaFX with Swing and I think the [JavaFX samples] includes the webView.[1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/index.html)

Comment: Does this also work in LWJGL (Can't seem to find the answer via googling)

Comment: LWJGL is pure Java, right? From a java app you can launch a JavaFX scene with a web view and point it to a web page of your choosing, provided the client desktop has the JavaFX runtime installed (which now cones with the latest Java 7 download automatically)

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm coming from a C# background into the game "Minecraft" modding. I don't know all the information I should about it, but I'll give this a try. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I have moved and re-sized Windows in a Windows platform setting. It's a small fraction of some of my User32 JNA Windows library code:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TestMoveWindow extends JPanel {
   public static final String[] BOUNDS_NAMES = { "x", "y", "w", "h" };
   private JTextField windowNameField = new JTextField(15);
   private JTextField[] boundsFields = new JTextField[BOUNDS_NAMES.length];

   public TestMoveWindow() {
      JPanel winNamePanel = new JPanel();
      winNamePanel.add(new JLabel("Window Name:"));
      winNamePanel.add(windowNameField);

      JPanel boundsPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, 5, 0));
      for (int i = 0; i < BOUNDS_NAMES.length; i++) {
         JPanel fieldPanel = new JPanel();
         fieldPanel.add(new JLabel(BOUNDS_NAMES[i] + ":"));
         boundsFields[i] = new JTextField(3);
         fieldPanel.add(boundsFields[i]);
         boundsPanel.add(fieldPanel);
      }

      JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();

      Action doItAction = new AbstractAction("Do it!") {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String startOfWindowName = windowNameField.getText().trim();
            Pointer hWnd = JnaUtil.getWinHwnd(startOfWindowName);
            if (hWnd == null || startOfWindowName.isEmpty()) {
               String message = String.format(
                     "Window named \"%s\" was not found", startOfWindowName);
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestMoveWindow.this, message,
                     "Window Not Found", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
               return;
            }
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            int w = 0;
            int h = 0;

            String xStr = boundsFields[0].getText();
            String yStr = boundsFields[1].getText();
            String wStr = boundsFields[2].getText();
            String hStr = boundsFields[3].getText();
            try {
               x = Integer.parseInt(xStr);
               y = Integer.parseInt(yStr);
               w = Integer.parseInt(wStr);
               h = Integer.parseInt(hStr);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
               String message = String
                     .format(
                           "Numbers cannot be parsed: \"%s\", \"%s\", \"%s\", \"%s\"",
                           xStr, yStr, wStr, hStr);
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestMoveWindow.this, message,
                     "Numbers Not Parseable", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
               return;
            }

            JnaUtil.moveWindow(hWnd, x, y, w, h);

         }
      };
      btnPanel.add(new JButton(doItAction));

      windowNameField.addActionListener(doItAction);
      for (JTextField boundField : boundsFields) {
         boundField.addActionListener(doItAction);
      }

      setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
      add(winNamePanel);
      add(boundsPanel);
      add(btnPanel);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Move Window");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new TestMoveWindow());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }

}

class JnaUtil {
   private static final User32 user32 = User32.INSTANCE;
   private static Pointer callBackHwnd;

   public static Pointer getWinHwnd(final String startOfWindowName) {
      callBackHwnd = null;

      user32.EnumWindows(new User32.WNDENUMPROC() {
         @Override
         public boolean callback(Pointer hWnd, Pointer userData) {
            byte[] windowText = new byte[512];
            user32.GetWindowTextA(hWnd, windowText, 512);
            String wText = Native.toString(windowText).trim();

            if (!wText.isEmpty() && wText.startsWith(startOfWindowName)) {
               callBackHwnd = hWnd;
               return false;
            }
            return true;
         }
      }, null);
      return callBackHwnd;
   }

   public static boolean moveWindow(Pointer hWnd, int x, int y, int nWidth,
         int nHeight) {
      boolean bRepaint = true;
      return user32.MoveWindow(hWnd, x, y, nWidth, nHeight, bRepaint);
   }

}

interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary {
   User32 INSTANCE = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class);

   interface WNDENUMPROC extends StdCallCallback {
      boolean callback(Pointer hWnd, Pointer arg);
   }

   boolean EnumWindows(WNDENUMPROC lpEnumFunc, Pointer userData);

   boolean MoveWindow(Pointer hWnd, int x, int y, int nWidth, int nHeight,
         boolean bRepaint);

   int GetWindowTextA(Pointer hWnd, byte[] lpString, int nMaxCount);

}
```

This would require that you have the jna.jar and platform.jar from the JNA library on your classpath. And again, this is for the Windows platform only. The first part of the code, the TestMoveWindow is simply a test GUI to demonstrate how the program works, and it really is little more than a call to `JnaUtil.moveWindow(hWnd, x, y, w, h);`, but the "meat" of the code is my JnaUtil class and User32 interface. The JNA library makes doing this *so* easy, it's ridiculous. For my code to work, you'd also need to know the start of the window text -- which is often the title of the web page -- so that it can get a Pointer to the Window.

I honestly don't know if any cross-platform solution exists. I'd like to think that there is, but I kind of doubt it since I believe that this would always require system calls, but I'd love to be proved wrong!

Comment: Even if no simple crossplatform solution exists, a solution for each main OS(Linux, Mac, Windows) should exist, correct?

Comment: @Gavin: Oh absolutely! But don't try to ask *me* anything at all about Unix, Mac, or anything other than Windows. :)